wordpress, drupal. free software
Have got a work assignment for a website where they are currently using wordpress. Been thinking about drupal with php.  What is the Gnu Project current advice for good websites?
Would like to use free software.
What would be good for back-end development? PHP, Java, Perl, Python, Ruby?  Any other language that is free software.  Some have suggested emacs org-mode, but I am not so sure.
